# Recursive way to find parent_id and convert a multidimensional array to one dimensional

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I want to convert a multidimensional array, like:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[853]
      public 'id' => int 1
      public 'children' => 
        array (size=5)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[852]
              public 'id' => int 31
              public 'children' => 
                array (size=2)
                  0 => 
                    object(stdClass)[854]
                      public 'id' => int 32
                  1 => 
                    object(stdClass)[855]
                      public 'id' => int 36
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[856]
              public 'id' => int 4
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[857]
              public 'id' => int 30
          3 => 
            object(stdClass)[858]
              public 'id' => int 8
          4 => 
            object(stdClass)[859]
              public 'id' => int 5
              public 'children' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => 
                    object(stdClass)[860]
                      public 'id' => int 7
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[861]
      public 'id' => int 2
      public 'children' => 
        array (size=8)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[862]
              public 'id' => int 14
              public 'children' => 
                array (size=7)
                  0 => 
                    object(stdClass)[863]
                      public 'id' => int 16
                  1 => 
                    object(stdClass)[864]
                      public 'id' => int 20
                  2 => 
                    object(stdClass)[865]
                      public 'id' => int 15
                  3 => 
                    object(stdClass)[866]
                      public 'id' => int 29
                  4 => 
                    object(stdClass)[867]
                      public 'id' => int 19
```

To something like:

```
[
    'id'        => 1,
    'parent_id' => 0
],
[
    'id'        => 31,
    'parent'    => 1
],
[
    'id'        => 32,
    'parent'    => 31
],
[
    'id'        => 36,
    'parent'    => 31   
],
[
    'id'        => 4,
    'parent'    => 1
],
[
    'id'        => 30,
    'parent'    => 1
],
[
    'id'        => 8,
    'parent'    => 1
],
[
    'id'        => 5,
    'parent'    => 1
],
[
    'id'        => 7,
    'parent'    => 5
],
[
    'id'        => 2,
    'parent'    => 0
],
[
    'id'        => 14,
    'parent'    => 2
],
[
    'id'        => 16,
    'parent'    => 14
],
[
    'id'        => 20,
    'parent'    => 14
]
```

But I can`t find a way to do that.
I tried to many ways, like:

```
public function linksRecursive($array, $res = [], $parent = 0)
{
    foreach($array as $arr)
    {
        $res[] = [
            'id' => $arr->id,
            'parent' => $parent
        ];
        // echo 'ID: ' . $arr->id . ', PARENT: ' . $parent . "<br>";
        $parent = $arr->id;
        if(isset($arr->children))
        {
            $this->linksRecursive($arr->children, $res, $parent);
        }
    }

    return $res;

}
```

What can I do to solve this problem? There is a way to do something?
I'm working with serialized sortable/nestable JQuery ui plugin, I'm build this to save the new order to my menu.

Comment: `public function linksRecursive($array, &$res = [], $parent = 0)`

Comment: Thanks! But now I'm with a little problem in parent_id :(

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple mistake, you need to set the $res as the result of you linksRecursive method.
Just do...

```
        $res = $this->linksRecursive($arr->children, $res, $parent);
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers!

I solved this question thanks to your answers!

```
public function linksRecursive(array $array, &$res = [], $parent = 0)
{
    foreach($array as $arr)
    {
        $res[] = [
            'id' => $arr->id,
            'parent' => $parent
        ];
        if(isset($arr->children))
        {
            $this->linksRecursive($arr->children, $res, $arr->id);
        }

    }

    return $res;

}
```